# Flatten layers for 1D convolution in Keras

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning

Is the use of layer_flatten function in Keras is required for 1D convolution in multiclass classification?

In the Keras R studio interface manual (https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/imdb_cnn.html). Why they have used the layer_flatten function only for 2D convolution?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about what **you** want. There are no obligations.

You need shapes that match your input and output data.

- `Conv1D` uses shapes `(batch, length, filters)` - 3D
- `Conv2D` uses shapes `(batch, x, y, filters)` - 4D
- `Flatten` makes everything become `(batch, productOfTheRest)` - 2D

Now you need to know what your data is, what you want to do with it and choose the proper layers/shapes.